# How to auto build Excel-DNA addin in VS 2019

Tags: excel, msbuild, msbuild-task, excel-dna

I am trying to auto pack Excel-DNA project.

I have followed [Getting Started with Excel-DNA](https://docs.excel-dna.net/getting-started/) to create Excel-DNA project.

I followed [Excel-DNA Packing Tool](https://docs.excel-dna.net/exceldna-packing-tool/) to pack my project which works.

I am trying to use VS 2019 post-build event to achieve auto pack my project.

I copied the `ExcelDna.Integration.dll`,`ExcelDnaPack.exe` and `ExcelDnaPack.exe.config` to my folder, and then use command below

```
ECHO "Start Deploy"
"$(SolutionDir)Distribution\ExcelDnaPack.exe" "$(TargetDir)$(TargetName)-AddIn.dna" /Y /O "$(TargetDir)DeployMeekou.ExcelCOM.xll"
```

But, it create the expected file. But, I got this file is invalid when I try to load it from Excel.

And checking build output, this is the output

```
1>  "Start Deploy"
1>  Using base add-in C:\Users\xx\Meekou.ExcelCOM\bin\Debug\Meekou.ExcelCOM-AddIn.xll
1>  System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The parameter is incorrect
1>     at ResourceHelper.ResourceUpdater.RemoveResource(String typeName, String name)
1>     at ExcelDnaPack.PackProgram.Pack(String[] args)
1>     at ExcelDnaPack.PackProgram.Main(String[] args)
```

Here are my project folder

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way these days to make a new Excel-DNA add-in is to use the "ExcelDna.AddIn" package on NuGet.

If you start with a new "Class Library (.NET Framework)" project, and install the package, it should just work and all the packing etc. steps are built in.

If you are using the new SDK-style project files or PackageReference style NuGet references (instead of a packages.config file) then you'll need the prerelease version 1.6.0-Preview2 or later of the ExcelDna.AddIn package.

The best place to ask questions about Excel-DNA is the Google group at https://groups.google.com/g/exceldna